# Can I pass a variable from one html page to another html page using php?

Tags: php, html, variables

The following code is not working:

code on page 1:

```
    <form action="phpTutorial.html" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
    Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

code on page 2:

```
    <br />
    Welcome <?php echo $_Post["fname"]; ?>!<br ?>
    You are <?php echo $_Post["age"]; ?> years old.
    <br />
```

Comment: I think you need to use capitals for 'POST'

Comment: What are file names? .php or .html - if .html have you tweaked server to render as php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using PHP on your code, so file name should be **phpTutorial.php** instead of phpTutorial.html. Correct Form action name

And  phpTutorial.php should have following code:

```
<br />
Welcome <?php echo $_Post["fname"]; ?>!<br ?>
You are <?php echo $_Post["age"]; ?> years old.
<br />
```

**$_Post** should be replaced by **$_POST**.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $_POST["fname"]
```

The inbuilt variables (is there a better name for those?) are all referenced in capitals, and PHP variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: It's an easy enough mistake to make - I think we've all done it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Action in the form should be `action="phpTutorial.php"` instead of`action="phpTutorial.html"` and `phpTutorial.php` should have

```
<br />
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br ?>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
<br />
```

When you will submit a form it'll launch the file in the from's action attribute you gave and in this case you give the name of the php file and it should be`phpTutorial.php`.